# Difference between It's sad and I am sad

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

When I heard a girl killed herself by drowning at 19 years old because her husband was killed in a war, I said to my friends:

> It is very sad to hear this news

I am wondering whether there are any differences in meaning if I said this instead:

> I am very sad to hear this news

Thank you for your reading.

Comment: Both examples are correct English. The first is a general statement that you hope others agree with. The second is a personal statement expressing your feelings. I don't understand the reason for your uncertainty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use *it* as in your example, but doing so makes the sentence passive, which may come across as a lack of concern or feeling regarding the news.

It would be OK to use *it* referring to the news, but it isn't when referring to yourself (or any person). Your first example is unclear about what *it* is actually referring to. You could say:

> It *was* very sad news that I heard today.

The second one is basically OK, but [*sadden*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sadden) might be a better word as your feelings are ongoing, so:

> I *was* really *saddened* to hear this news.

Both in the past tense since you heard the news in the past.